# Clearing/Updating parent field value after child Object delete

Tags: trigger

I have  object document__c, which contains field "contentdocumentids". i will populate "contentdocumentids" based on file insertion(In case of document level) .

In case of delete I have to populate recently created content document in "contentdocumentids" and if there is no content document i have to make "contentdocumentid" has to be null.

```
   if(trigger.isdelete && trigger.isAfter){
    map<id,id> contentmap=new map<id,id>();
    set<id> contentdocumentIds=new set<id>();
    set<id> LinkedEntityId=new set<id>();
    List<Document__c> documentToUpdate = new List<Document__c>();

    for(ContentDocumentLink con:trigger.old){
        contentdocumentIds.add(con.ContentDocumentId);
       LinkedEntityId.add(con.linkedEntityId);

    }

      ContentDocumentLink con =[select id,linkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink 
                         where  linkedEntityId in:LinkedEntityId and id not in:contentdocumentIds
                         ORDER BY ContentDocument.CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
                        ];
      system.debug('con#####'+con);
         for(Document__c doc:[select id,Document__c, Content_Document_Ids__c from Document__c where id in:LinkedEntityId]){
        if(con==null ){
            doc.Content_Document_Ids__c='';
        }else{

                doc.Content_Document_Ids__c=con.ContentDocumentId;
            }
             documentToUpdate.add(doc);
        }
        update documentToUpdate ;
    }


}
```

Comment: What error are you getting, What result you are getting ?

Comment: parent field values isnot clearing after deleting it

Comment: Your SOQL is currently not syntactically valid. Is this your running version of this code?

Comment: Yes @David Reed. Whats the changes I have to make. seems like I have problem in this line:ContentDocumentLink contentdoc=[select id,linkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink where linkedEntityId in:acid and  ORDER BY ContentDocument.createdDate DESC LIMIT 1];

Comment: I'm voting to close because no specific question is being asked and the content has been replaced with new material.

Comment: okay make it close.I will open new question

Comment: I posted new question.i will make it as best answer because of your suggestion it surely helps to other community people looking for same answer.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: the content of this answer no longer specifically targets the question as the asker has removed and replaced much of the code that was originally posted.

The logic of this trigger doesn't make sense for your objective.

So you have `acid`, a Set of the Ids of linked entities, and you have `contentmap`, a map of `ContentDocument` Ids to linked entity ids.

```
ContentDocumentLink contentdoc=[select id,linkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink where linkedEntityId in:acid and  ORDER BY ContentDocument.createdDate DESC LIMIT 1];
```

Here, you're pulling out exactly one `ContentDocument`, the earliest created one attached to *any* of the linked entities for the `ContentDocument` records that are being deleted.

Additionally, as noted in the comments, this SOQL does not appear to be valid. You have a spurious `and` keyword without another clause.

```
for(Document__c doc:[select id,Document__c, Content_Document_Ids__c from Document__c where id in:contentmap.values()]){

    if(contentdoc.Id==null){
        doc.Content_Document_Ids__c ='';
```

`contentDoc.Id` will never be `null`. If your query above failed to find any records, it would throw an exception.

```
    }else if(contentdoc.Id!=null){
        doc.Content_Document_Ids__c=contentdoc.Id;
```

This doesn't do what you seem to want it to do. Basically, what's going to happen here is for every `Document__c` to which any deleted `ContentDocument` record was linked, you're going to overwrite its `Content_Document_Ids__c` field with the Id of a single, more-or-less randomly chosen `ContentDocument`, which is likely to be attached to some other `Document__c` because of the way you query. It definitely will not maintain a list of attached documents, nor will it populate the Id of a single document linked to each record.

Here is what I would recommend for this type of trigger workflow.

1. If it is an option, use Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries instead of rolling your own roll-up trigger code. (This is always my advice, as manually developing rollups is tricky and error-prone).
2. If you must develop this from scratch, factor out code from your trigger that queries for linked ContentDocuments and creates the Id strings you need.  Its signature could look like this:

   `public static Map<Id, String> getDocumentIdStringsForObjects(Set<Id> objectIds);`

In a bulkified manner, that method should query the ContentDocuments attached to records whose Ids are in `objectIds` and return a Map from the Object Id to the string of one or more `ContentDocument` Ids as needed by your requirements.

Then, your triggers need to do little more than identify those records for which the set of ContentDocuments has changed, call your static handler method (critically, the *same* bulkified static handler method) and perform updates appropriately.

Comment: hi david..i have updated the post..i would like to change that query it seems..please have a look

Comment: I would like to discuss about trigger. i dont want to do with declartive way.please check my trigger let me know where iam going wrong

Comment: My answer did provide some suggestions about your issues, but you've since removed all the original code and put new code into your question. Iteratively debugging your work is *not* what Stack Exchange is for. If you continue to have *specific, definable issues*, you need to ask one or more *specific, definable questions*.

Comment: Hi @David Reed below code works for me.Please check it let me know your suggestions